# How to run docker in docker in Gitlab ci?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I have /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

```
[[runners]]
  name = "My Docker Runner"
  url = "###"
  token = "###"
  executor = "docker"
  pre_clone_script = "git config --global http.sslVerify false"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "tiangolo/docker-with-compose"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    Insecure = false
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - test

before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk upgrade
  - apk add make

test:
  stage: test
  tags: [test]
  script:
    - make prod-up # docker-compose up -d --build
    - make composer-init-dev
    - make test
```

When I run the script in gitlab, I get the error:

$make prod-up
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --build
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http://docker:2375 - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
make: *** [Makefile:16: docker-prod-up] Error 1
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing Docker service (and it's best to specify image explicitly):

```
stages:
  - test

before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk upgrade
  - apk add make

test:
  stage: test
  image: tiangolo/docker-with-compose:latest
  services:
  - docker:dind
  tags: [test]
  script:
    - make prod-up # docker-compose up -d --build
    - make composer-init-dev
    - make test
```

Answer (score -1):

Try mounting docker.sock:

```
test:
  stage: test
  tags: [test]
  script:
    - make prod-up # docker-compose up -d --build
    - make composer-init-dev
    - make test
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```